# Cordova Multipage application - onDeviceReady to be included in all page

Tags: android, html, cordova

I am developing multi-page Cordova Phone application fo Android. I am using cordova.2.1 .
Seems like I need to include callback function -**onDeviceReady**() in all the pages of my application

Two questions

1. What would be the performance impact if I need to initialize cordova in all the pages
2. Is there a workaround, so I need to have callback only on my first page and in subsequent pages I can call cordova.exec directly

Thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance impact will be definitely slower, as your pages every time will try to check your Cordova is ready to use or not. (had own experience with this phenomenon).

If you are going to use cordova on all pages then you need to include ondeviceready callback on those pages.

additional info: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.phonegap/8460